# Assigning indexes to subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I need help figuring out how to assign an index to subarrays. Here is what I have so far:

I start off by setting up the array with the first subarray and some data.

`$start=array(array($rand, $_POST['day'], $_POST['time'], $delay));`

Then when I need to add another subarray, I use the array_push method to add subarrays to the existing array.

`$array = get_option('extend-array');

$push = array($rand, $_POST['day'], $_POST['time'], $delay);

array_push($array, $push);`

I'm not sure where to go from here. I want to have a custom index assigned to the subarrays so I can reference them directly if needed.

Comment: `get_option()` is not a PHP method. You haven't described your actual problem (or even end goal). What data do you have? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @EsbenTind get_option() is a function used in Wordpress. The code is from a plugin I am working on. I just needed to know how to assign an index to a subarray. Kolink answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign to the array elements:

```
$array = array(array($rand,$_POST['day'],$_POST['time'],$delay));
$array[1] = array("New data");
$array[2] = "Blah";
$array[9001] = "Doesn't have to be consecutive.";
```

Answer (score 0):

push just stuffs in another element, at the next highest available index. If you want a custom index, you'll have to define it yourself, e.g.

```
$array = array('rand' => $rand, 'day' => $_POST['day'], etc...);
$array['extended-array'] = get_option('extend-array');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly trivial. In PHP you can define arrays as you go. Just start with an empty variable, and add the subarrays you want:

```
$array["start"] = array($rand, $_POST['day'], $_POST['time'], $delay);
```

Then add another one:

```
$array["push"] = get_option('extend-array');
```

Also check the manual examples http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
$start = array(array($rand, $_POST['day'], $_POST['time'], $delay));
$start['extend-array']= array($rand, $_POST['day'], $_POST['time'], $delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to assign the key name when creating the array is:

$array = array('key_name' => 'value');

You can set the index of the sub array when creating it:

Your code should change to:

```
$start=array(array('rand' => $rand, 'post_day' => $_POST['day'], 'post_time' => $_POST['time'], 'delay' => $delay));
```

and then you can acces to the index like this:

$start[0]['rand'] = 'new rand value';
$start[0]['post_day'] = 'new post_day value';

and so on